# Copy Solr Field Values via Script

Tags: solr

I would like to copy the data from one field to another field for all documents in Solr.

A title field that is already populated needs to be copied into another field I just created. I'd like to do them all at once if possible via Putty or the Solr Admin console.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can modify the solr schma.xml and mention all the source fields and target field where you want to copy the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have pre-ingested data then the only option is to re-ingest the data after adding the second field. You can set only the new field in the docs instead of inserting all the fields using Solr atomic updates. https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html#atomic-updates

```
solr.add({'id':1, 'newField': {'set': 'sample value'}})
```

For future insertions, if you want the second field to be auto filled, you can use Solr copy field with the source set to the first field. https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_6/copying-fields.html